# CodeIgniter - Undefined Property Error

Tags: php, codeigniter, properties, undefined

I am trying to access all the bands in my table and print them out in a list, but when I run it I get this error:

```
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: CI_Loader::$model_bands

Filename: views/band_view.php

Line Number: 16
```

band_view.php:

```
<h3>List of Bands:</h3>
<?php
$bands = $this->model_bands->getAllBands();

echo $bands;
?>
```

model_bands.php:

```
function getAllBands() {
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT band_name FROM bands');
    return $query->result();    
}
```

Could someone pleease tell me why it is doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need to do this, the correct way is to use the model methods inside a controller, then passing it to the view:

```
public function controller_name()
{
    $data = array();
    $this->load->model('Model_bands'); // load the model
    $bands = $this->model_bands->getAllBands(); // use the method
    $data['bands'] = $bands; // put it inside a parent array
    $this->load->view('view_name', $data); // load the gathered data into the view
}
```

And then use `$bands` (loop) in the view.

```
<h3>List of Bands:</h3>
<?php foreach($bands as $band): ?>
    <p><?php echo $band->band_name; ?></p><br/>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Are you sure its foreach($bands as $band)? Because its saying the variable bands doesnt exist

Answer (score 1):

Did you load your model in the Controller?

```
    $this->load->model("model_bands");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your code like
Controller

```
public function AllBrands() 
{
    $data = array();
    $this->load->model('model_bands'); // load the model
    $bands = $this->model_bands->getAllBands(); // use the method
    $data['bands'] = $bands; // put it inside a parent array
    $this->load->view('band_view', $data); // load the gathered data into the view
}
```

Then View

```
<h3>List of Bands:</h3>
<?php foreach($bands as $band){ ?>
    <p><?php echo $band->band_name; ?></p><br/>
<?php } ?>
```

Your Model is ok

```
function getAllBands() {
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT band_name FROM bands');
    return $query->result();    
}
```

Comment: Are you sure its foreach($bands as $band)? Because its saying the variable bands doesnt exist

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to load the model on your controller:

```
//controller

function __construct()
{
    $this->load->model('model_bands'); // load the model
}
```

BTW, why are you calling the model directly from your view? Should it be:

```
//model
$bands = $this->model_bands->getAllBands();
$this->load->view('band_view', array('bands' => $bands));

//view
<h3>List of Bands:</h3>
<?php echo $bands;?>
```